# Windows IIS ARR Reverse Proxy Encoding Issue

Tags: iis, proxy, character-encoding, header, arr

We have an environment with an Windows 2019 Server IIS 10, which is acting as Reverse Proxy (ARR) for my IIS Server farm (Application Request Routing 3.0 and URL Rewrite 2.1). We send the users name in the HTTP headers. But my ARR somehow screws up the encoding (we are using german special characters, e.g. ö,ü,ß...), so when i check the respone of the WebServer it shows me: H%C3%B6lmuth M%C3%A4%C3%9Fterm%C3%BCller instead of Hölmuth Mäßtermüller.

I have an old environment with Windows 2012R2 Server with the same configuration, in this environment the display of the name is correct. I have checked all kind of settings between old and new servers, but cannot find any difference.

Futher i have used Failed Request Loggins and Network Monitor to see what the server receives and sends, below find the results.

Received Request on the IIS ARR (old and new):
X-AUTHENTICATE-FamilyName: M%C3%A4%C3%9Fterm%C3%Bcller
X-AUTHENTICATE-GivenName: H%C3%83%C2%B6lmuth
X-AUTHENTICATE-cn: H%C3%B6lmuth M%C3%A4%C3%9Fterm%C3%BCller

Request send to the IIS (new):
X-AUTHENTICATE-FamilyName:  M%C3%A4%C3%9Fterm%C3%BCller
X-AUTHENTICATE-GivenName:  H%C3%83%C2%B6lmuth
X-AUTHENTICATE-cn:  H%C3%B6lmuth M%C3%A4%C3%9Fterm%C3%BCller

Request send to the IIS (old):
X-AUTHENTICATE-FamilyName:  Mäßtermüller
X-AUTHENTICATE-GivenName:  HÃ¶lmuth
X-AUTHENTICATE-cn:  Hölmuth Mäßtermüller

Anyone has an idea how i can change this behaviour? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give me an example how to use the {UNENCODED_URL} variable. Currently we are using the rewrite module to route requests to specific Server Farms, see my rules below:

```
 <rewrite>
        <globalRules useOriginalURLEncoding="true">
            <rule name="ARR_BPBP-DEV_loadbalance" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://BPBP-DEV/{R:0}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="bmi-bpbp-dev.vecos.at" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
            <rule name="ARR_BPBP-TEST_loadbalance" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://BPBP-TEST/{R:0}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="bmi-bpbp-test.vecos.at" />
                </conditions>
                <serverVariables>
                </serverVariables>
            </rule>
        </globalRules>
```

How can i adapt the rules to use the {UNENCODED_URL} variable?

Comment: you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#preserving-original-url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#preserving-original-url) and [https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/url-rewrite-v2-1](https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/url-rewrite-v2-1).

Answer (score 0):

When an HTTP request arrives on Windows, the latest HTTP.sys encodes both URL and HTTP headers, and puts the original URL in `UNENCODED_URL` server variable so that it can be recovered afterwards.

However, the original headers (such as `X-AUTHENTICATE-FamilyName: Mäßtermüller`) do not seem to be preserved (no clear documentation on that), so there isn't any easy way to recover them.

If you want to modify the the header from `X-AUTHENTICATE-FamilyName: M%C3%A4%C3%9Fterm%C3%BCller` back to `X-AUTHENTICATE-FamilyName: Mäßtermüller`, the only way I can think of is to write a custom IIS module to perform the decoding step.

Alternatively, you might modify your other code to accept such encoded header values (and decode them when needed in your code), as anyway that's how Windows/IIS behaves now and you cannot fight it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the `useOriginalURLEncoding` to false, and URL rewrite will no longer encode the urls when using the {UNENCODED_URL} variable in the rules.

To set the flag to go IIS Manager then select `Configuration Editor` and go to the section `system.webServer/rewrite/rules`, where you will find the `useOriginalURLEncoding` flag.

Comment: Thanks for you reply samwu. Please check above for clarification.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is about HTTP headers, such as `X-AUTHENTICATE-FamilyName: Mäßtermüller`. Those were encoded by newer version of HTTP.sys, and this user wanted to disable that encoding process. Neither `useOriginalURLEncoding` nor `UNENCODED_URL` helps.